# wordpress redirect loop on mod rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have wordpress setup to change the admin url to www.mydomain.com/admin. But now I have updated the permalinks to use the post name instaed of the id I get a redirect loop when I try to access the admin page. The problem is with the extra rules wordpress asked me to add to the .htaccess but I am unsure how to change it to allow both rules.

Wordpress 3.5.2 rewrite rules as below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Anyone know what i need to do to allow both rules?

Comment: Try putting your last rule higher up, before now second last one that rewrites everything to index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was trying out a few solutions and it would seem that having the rewrite rule for changing the admin url to www.mydomain.com/admin BEFORE the mod-rewrite rules is the key to allowing both rules to work together. See updated/fixed .htaccess code below.

```
    RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```